# UIScrollView Scrolling problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want Newsweek i pad app like scrolling on detail news.I have done like that but it's scrolling only.for e.g if you have 10 articles. on first page you click on article 3 then it show 3rd articles detail news and scrolls left upto 10 but not scrolls right side 3 ,2

Answer (score 0):

same Question again.... never mind

(1) Create View Controller and add scroll view from IB and link it with outlet variable

```
-(void)createScrollView
{
myScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 440)];
myScroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
myScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
myScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
myScroll.scrollsToTop = NO;
myScroll.delegate = self;
int n = [array count];
myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake((320 * n), 440);

for (int i = 0 , X = 0; i < [photoArray count]; i++ , X += 320) 
{
    UIImageView *img =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X,0, 320, 480)]; //here web view for you

    CGRect frame;
    frame.size.width=320; frame.size.height=240;
    frame.origin.x=0; frame.origin.y=88;


    [img addSubview:asyncImage];
    img.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;            

    [myScroll addSubview:img];
}
}

 - (void) viewDidLoad
  {
[self createScrollView];
[myScroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320*photoNumber, 0, 320 , 240) animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:myScroll];        
  }
```

its a sample code .... try it with changes... hope that finally work for you...

Comment: yes i have done like this this will show webview starting value from first item in array i want if some one has news 3rd item of array then

Comment: means ? you mean if you press 3rd page then its should show 3rd one ?

Comment: yes its should show 3rd page as i have done but its scrolls to 4 5 6 not remaining 21

Comment: what happens if you scroll to the previous web view ?

Comment: it does not scroll to previous webview seen is that in my loop if textview 3 is clicked that value is passed then this will load articles from 3rd not from first that's why its not scrolling so any idea to do that

Comment: try to create another method with an argument of int type. and write the code  [myScroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320*pageNumber, 0, 320 , 240) animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:myScroll];    in it. now when you click on page number button then pass the page number to this method.

Comment: i have scrollview created in IB so how may give the values CGRectMake(320*pageNumber, 0, 320 , 240)

Comment: in your .h file IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScroll; then link it with the scroll view in IB

Comment: yes i have done but not working its loading page from first according to your code

Comment: then what you want ? from where it should start.. ?

Comment: i want that it should start from as i said if 3rd news is then start from 3rd and also should scroll back to 2 and one

Comment: tell me the width of your web view ?

Comment: CGRect mywebframe=CGRectMake(0, 30, 768, 876);

Comment: then u have modify like myScroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(768*pageNumber, 0, 320 , 240) animated:NO];

Comment: can u give me your email id if you don't mind i send you code to check

Answer (score 0):

pass the value to the photoNumber.. E.g for 3rd article 3..

Comment: when i will pass the value then it will move to 3rd page and load all items

Comment: Then change the value of X to pageNumber*320.. for the first article it should be 0.